# how to get value between points from a plot?

Tags: matlab

Consider that I have the following sets of values,

```
Y = [1  23  4  67  89  23  5   12 ]
X = [0  2   4  6   10  14  18  22 ]
```

I can draw a plot with the basic plot function. Now, from this plot, I want to know what the Y value for X=5. How can I get this data?

You can see, it's not part of my plot points, but something I was to extract from the graph.

Any ideas folks? I'm a bit surprised that there isn't a built in function for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html)

For your example, the code would be

```
 y = interp1(X, Y, 5, 'linear');
```

Comment: That link was handy to understand the function (saved me the trouble of searching for it). I KNEW that there had to be a built-in function to do this, but I kept searching with terms like 'data extrapolation' and kept running into dead ends. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 4):

Since plot uses linear interpolation, you should use it as well.

```
   y = interp1(X,Y,5);
```